# In Python is it possible to split a list in first, inner and last element in one expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

Imagine a string `s="one two  three   four five"`. I'd like to split it into it's first, last and the 'inner' element. I know I can do this with clever unpacking and re-joining:

```py
first, *rest, last = s.split(" ")
middle = " ".join(rest)
print(first, middle, last)
```

Is it possible to do this in one expression? (i.e. maybe without splitting the whole string string first and re-joining it afterwards)

Comment: Your current method is clean and readable. I don’t think it is necessary to sacrifice that for 1 line’s saving.

Comment: You're right - I would not sacrifice readability. Was just hoping for some `split()` feature like  `first, middle, last = s.split(" ", 1, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it in 2 steps using `split` and `rsplit` is the most readable, sensible and fastest solution

```
first, rest = s.split(' ', 1)
middle, last = rest.rsplit(' ', 1)
```

But if you still think, you like to do in one step, you can do it using `re.split`

```
first, middle, last = re.split(r' +(.*) +', s)
```

Comment: This is not one step

Comment: Yes.. Thats why I said doing it in 2 lines (aka steps) is most readable and sensible

Comment: @U10-Forward. Updated my answer with a single step solution

Answer (score 3):

With `re` module ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uyGkyX/1)):

```
s="one two  three   four five"

import re
first, middle, last = re.findall(r'(\S+)\s*(.*)\s+(\S+)', s)[0]

print(first)
print(middle)
print(last)
```

Prints:

```
one
two  three   four
five
```

Comment: It does answer OP's request but I think it's a shame to have to resort to a regexp for such a simple usecase.

Comment: While this is indeed the shortest way to do it, it is also more or less unreadable. I would never advise to actually put that into code, even though it might save you a line.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly it is possible.

```
import re

fmlre = re.compile('^([^ ]*) (.*) ([^ ]*)$')

first, middle, last = fmlre.match("hello my old friend").groups()
```

You could also do it using `index` and `rindex`, but it's frequently more efficient to let `re` do the entire search in one pass. Another thing to consider when making an expression like this is to create a function; it matters little how many lines are in the function when each call uses a simple descriptive name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and `rfind`:

```
first, middle, last = [s.split(' ', 1)[0], *s.split(' ', 1)[1].rsplit(' ', 1)]
```

And now:

```
print(middle)
```

Is:

```
two  three   four
```

Comment: hm. the full expression would be `first, middle, last = s[:s.find(" ")],s[s.find(' ') + 1: s.rfind(' ')], s[s.rfind(" ") + 1:]`, which - in my eyes does not count as "one expression" :)

Comment: @frans How about now?

Answer (score 0):

```
s="one two  three   four five"
" ".join(s.split(' ')[1:-1])
```

---

or `print(*s.split(' ')[1:-1])`

Comment: Does this count as one step?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `re`, namely `re.split` function:

```
import re
s="one two  three   four five"
first,middle,last = re.split(r'\s(.*)\s',s)
print(first) #one
print(middle) #two  three   four
print(last) #five
```

Note that spaces (`\s`) in first argument of `re.split` are outside group (denoted by brackets) so will be jettisoned, also note that `.*` is *greedy* (will match as many characters as possible) which is crucial to proper functioning of this approach.